# How do I change Firefox letterbox size?

Tags: customization

`privacy.resistFingerprinting.letterboxing.dimensions` doesn't do anything or I don't know how to type the command correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It's hardcoded into it to make all it's users look alike to each other to enharden detection. You need a virtual machine routed through Tor with a normal browser to browse as usual